# How do I create a Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Someone please tell me how to create a Minecraft server.

Answer (score 4):

The short story is you grab the server from [here](http://minecraft.net/download.jsp) and launch it using Java like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -Xms1G -Xmx1G ^
                                           -jar Minecraft_Server.exe nogui
```

...or

```
java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

...making sure you adjust the paths for both `java` and `minecraft_server.jar`to accomodate your system setup.

The long story is told in excruciating detail [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server).

Answer (score 2):

1. First, you will need to open a port on your router, so people outside your house can connect. This is different based on what router you have, but the router's settings page is usually a good place to start
2. Next, you will need to get the Minecraft Server software. If you're on Windows, you can just download the EXE file and double click it to start the server. For Mac or Linux, use the JAR file and use `java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar (where you saved the JAR file) nogui` to start it

   - Note that the server's files will be created wherever you saved the EXE file. You might want to move it first
3. Finally, you can start minecraft and log into your server by clicking "Add Server" and then using `localhost:25565` However, for your friends, you'll need to give them your external IP address. You can find this by type in `What's My IP Address?` into Google, then adding `:25565` at the end.

The settings of your server are saved in a file called `server.properties`. You can change things like the server port or the default game mode.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule of making a public server is "If you have to ask, you shouldn't." That said, if you're still determined, this should help: [Tutorial](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server)

Good luck! :)

Comment: Yeeeaaah… that's pretty good advice actually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying under a Windows environment, I wrote [YAMS](http://yams.in/) to automate all of the steps and make management easier.

YAMS includes UPnP port mapping, automatic updates and web-based control.  Details are all on the linked website, and it's open source.

Comment: You write YAMS? Doesn't seem legit

Comment: Admittedly it hasn't been updated in a long time due to work and family commitments, but it still (mostly) works. What doesn't seem legit about it?